# transform a svg into a copy/paste-able emoticon like this one 

Tags: image, svg, image-processing

Not sure if SO is the best place for this question, but don't know where else to ask.

Is there any way to transform a svg like this one for ex: (https://svgsilh.com/image/1775543.html) into something that i can use inside an editor with copy/paste like this one?

Comment: I guess you need to make a font with your drawing, then you can load the font in the editor. https://www.colorfonts.wtf/

Comment: No. The reason you can "copy and paste" that icon is that the icon already has a UTF-8 code and your editor is UTF-8 aware.
And this is why the same emoticon is slightly different between Apple, Android and so on: it's because it's always code XYZ, but code XYZ is rendered with different icons on different platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the unicorn emoticon is one example of a *character*.  And just as with letters, digits, and punctuation, the appearance of emoticons and other plain-text symbols is decided by *fonts*.

LSerni wrote the following:

> The reason you can "copy and paste" that icon is that the icon already has a UTF-8 code and your editor is UTF-8 aware. And this is why the same emoticon is slightly different between Apple, Android and so on: it's because it's always code XYZ, but code XYZ is rendered with different icons on different platforms.

But that's not entirely correct.  The difference in rendering lies more in the *font* than in the operating system that displays emoticons. Unless the font supplies its own version of a symbol, that symbol will usually be supplied by the font specified by default by the operating system, and different operating systems supply different symbol fonts.